# How to reset PC firmware to normal?

Tags: windows-10, boot

I was installing Fedora (a Linux distro) on my PC and I had to force quit in the middle of installation. After that my computer (XPS 13) refused to boot properly until:

1. A factory image of Windows was installed on my computer by the Dell Support Assist Program.
2. I disabled Secure Boot and let rEFInd, which I had previously installed, boot into Windows for me.

Because of this - I'm guessing rEFInd is still installed on my computer. I'd like to, if possible, reset my computer's firmware to its original state - without rEFind or any modifications - so that I can re-enable Secure Boot.

How can I go about resetting my firmware to its original state?

Comment: rEFInd isn’t part of the firmware. It resides on your HDD/SSD.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to remove the UEFI firmware boot entry for rEFInd, and then rEFInd itself from the EFI System Partition (ESP).

To remove the firmware boot entry in Windows:

1.) run Command Prompt *as an administrator*

2.) type `bcdedit /enum FIRMWARE` to view the boot entries

3.) find the "Firmware Application" block in the output that refers to `refind.efi`, and note the GUID string in its `identifier` field.

4.) type `bcdedit /delete <GUID string from step 3 within curly braces>`

This should remove rEFInd from your firmware boot menus and let your system boot Windows normally.

To remove rEFInd from ESP (not technically necessary, but for the sake of completeness):

1.) run Command Prompt *as an administrator*

2.) type `mountvol X: /S`. This will make the ESP visible as Windows drive letter X:

3.) using either the Command prompt or an explorer.exe running *as an administrator*, go to `X:\EFI\` and identify the directory containing rEFInd. It will be named either `refind` or the name of the Linux distribution. Just delete that directory and everything within it. *Don't* delete the `X:\EFI\Microsoft` directory, or any other files in `X:\EFI`.

4.) Hide the ESP again by typing `mountvol X: /D` to the Administrator Command Prompt.

If you had to do a `mvrefind /boot/efi/EFI/refind /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT` with rEFInd earlier, and rEFInd still appears after performing all these steps, then the installation of Windows did not overwrite the EFI fallback boot file `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`. To fix this, enable access to the ESP again, and **copy** `X:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi` to `X:\EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1.Go to **Settings**
2.**Update & security**
3.**Recovery**
4.**Reset this PC**
5.Get started and choose an **option**.

The following information are about the options.

**Keep my files**
Reinstalls Windows 10 and keeps your personal files.
Removes apps and drivers you installed.
Removes changes you made to settings.
Removes any apps your PC manufacturer installed. (If your PC came with Windows 10, apps from your PC manufacturer will be reinstalled.)

**Remove everything**
Reinstalls Windows 10 and removes all your personal files.
Removes apps and drivers you installed.
Removes changes you made to settings.
Removes any apps your PC manufacturer installed. (If your PC came with Windows 10, apps from your PC manufacturer will be reinstalled.)
If you're planning to donate, recycle, or sell your PC, use this option and choose to fully clean the drive. This might take an hour or two, but it makes it harder for other people to recover files you've removed.

**Restore factory settings**
Reinstalls the version of Windows that your PC came with (either Windows 8 or Windows 8.1) and removes your personal files.
Removes apps and drivers you installed.
Removes changes you made to settings.
Reinstalls any apps your PC manufacturer installed on your PC.
This option isn't available on all PCs.