# How to get into UEFI BIOS if flash screen does no longer show & default keypress no longer works?

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, uefi

To prepare a PC for an upgrade from Win 10 to Win 11 and making triple-booting into Linux and Haiku easier, I switched the partitioning scheme of the boot drive from MBR to GPT.
This worked fine.

Then I disabled CSM (enables booting from MBR media) in the BIOS settings to switch to UEFI boot only.
This also worked fine.

But Windows System Information still showed "Secure Boot State" as "Off" (BIOS Mode is correctly shown as "UEFI").

No settings in the UEFI BIOS seemed to allow Secure Boot to be turned on or off, or to reset some TPM keys.

Googled a bit. Found articles on how to access UEFI settings from "within" Windows.

**Booted into the blue "troubleshooting settings" option from Windows restart.
There I selected to boot into the UEFI settings.**

**Since then** the BIOS splash screen is no longer showing, the keypress to enter the BIOS is no longer accepted, and the PC boots straight into Win 10 (so not into the BIOS as it should after using that troubleshooting option at boot time).

Motherboard: Gigabyte Z370M-DS3H with AMI BIOS F14 (latest version)
CPU: Intel Core i7 8700K ("soft" TPM2.0 supported)
OS: Win 10 Pro 64bit 22H2 fully patched

BIOS settings: Fast Boot was disabled. Splash screen should be shown. Integral GPU off (2 displays are connected via an NVidia GFX card).

What I tried already:

- Holding down the key to enter the BIOS setup, even when no splash screen is showing. Boots into Win.
- Reset via reset switch
- Power down, power up again
- Windows restart via "Restart" and "Restart" + SHIFT and then troubleshooting boot into UEFI settings again (just restarts into Win again)
- "shutdown /r /fw" in an admin shell doing the same as "Restart" + SHIFT + troubleshooting boot into UEFI settings again (just restarts into Win again)
- Removed SATA connector from boot drive. Leading to some checking of the other disks, then the main monitor turning off without a signal. No error msg whatsoever.
- Re-flashing BIOS F14 from inside Windows again. Downgrade of BIOS is not allowed there. Cleaning DMI settings also not allowed from the GUI flasher.
- Short the pins on the MB to clear the CMOS RAM. Didn't do anything. Maybe I hit the wrong ones, didn't do it long enough, whatever.

What I can still try:

- Try to clear the CMOS RAM again, maybe now with removing the battery, but this is tricky with this board and the GFX card blocking easy access.
- Boot some Linux or Haiku from optical disc or USB stick. But then, err, what?
- Connect internal GPU to one of the monitors. But the internal GPU is disabled in the BIOS, so should not work.

Any more ideas?

Comment: You will never get to Windows 11 that way.  Can you do a vendor certified BIOS (UEFI) update?   Also use virtualization instead of triple boot. Triple boot will be a fine way to hose Windows 11.

Comment: **You absolutely cannot access UEFI from within Windows** Whatever you read was likely generated by ChatGPT or a clueless individual. It honestly sounds like the device is bricked

Comment: And in addition proper UEFI (you need to get into BIOS (UEFI)

Comment: @Lunovus - That is common knowledge. Unfortunately, without access to UEFI, you are sort of stuck.

Comment: You seem to be going in circles somewhat.  Do a Manufacturer certified BIOS (UEFI) Update and see if you can get working that way.

Comment: AMI BIOS F14 IS the latest official UEFI BIOS.
I can re-flash it.
But it doesn't change a thing.

Comment: If you truly updated UEFI BIOS and still cannot get into settings, something is very seriously wrong with your machine.

Comment: I didn't update the UEFI BIOS.
It was already at the latest official version.
I just re-flashed it, hoping the UEFI BIOS settings would have been reset too.
Didn't work.

Comment: You probably need to take the machine to a repair shop.

Comment: The PC ain't bricked, it just boots fine into Win 10.
It just doesn't boot into the UEFO BIOS settings anymore.
And there pretty much is nothing a repair shop can do that I can't.
Just need to know what options are left.

Comment: They can replace (maybe) the BIOS Chip.

Comment: One thing you can try on a Linux live is `efibootmgr`. It can theoretically be used to adjust the UEFI splash timeout. You may give it a try but it might not help, **and it can be somewhat risky given that your UEFI firmware sound bugged/flawed**, since what you experienced is not something that is expected. (Sounds like using `BootNext` or so can make your UEFI firmware semi-bricked.)

Comment: You may also *install* (i.e., afresh) Windows 11 without Secure Boot enabled, by using command line programs `dism` and `bcdboot` (and probably `diskpart` as well) instead of the GUI Windows Setup.

Comment: Note that 'access UEFI settings from "within" Windows' (i.e. Advanced Startup) should normally just get you to the very same UEFI setting "portal" that you will get to by pressing specific key upon/before the boot splash shows up. Beside, AFAIK AMI UEFI do not support the Advanced Startup method because unlike Pheonix UEFI, it does not have builtin UEFI boot entry that would lead you to the UEFI settings. (You can check that with `efibootmgr` as well.)

Comment: @Lunovus - No, wonder I am confused, I thought Windows was bootable (your question contents suggests that’s the case)

Comment: @Ramhound - Yes, Windows is and was bootable (but now it's Win 11 instead of Win10).

Comment: Thanks Tom Yan for the info about efibootmgr.
After some more googling I found https://superuser.com/questions/1344342/how-to-reset-pc-firmware-to-normal about programs that might do (nearly) the same on Win.
I think I found some and that bcdedit may be showing (and allows) to edit the kinda "1st stage" of boot that should be used (stored in NVRAM).
So can some people tell me what their output is for "bcdedit /enum firmware" in an admin shell?

Comment: Mine is:
"Firmware Boot Manager
---------------------
identifier              {fwbootmgr}
displayorder            {bootmgr}
timeout                 1

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume3
path                    \EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI
[..]"

But maybe yours is different?

Comment: More infos *sigh*.
Tried again and now succeded in reseting the CMOS RAM.
Was able to able to enter the BIOS setup after two reboots again.
Set up some values (like disabling CSM, to enable Win 11 to boot).
Saved and reboot.
Win 11 boots like before.
No splash screen for BIOS setup (like before).

I want to boot some Linux and Haiku, how can I install those without installing something like reFINd (or what's it spelled) before?

I want to access my BIOS settings without misshandling my MB with a screwdriver!

Answer (score 0):

For anybody having the same or a similar problem:

What finally helped me was clearing the NVRAM (or CMOS RAM) by shortening the needed pins on the mainboard with a detached power cord.

Then I **didn't** re-disabled the CSM option (the setting that allows booting older (MBR) boot sectors).

Windows 11 would still boot, and still showed the boot mode as "UEFI" in System Information.

It seems Windows (or the UEFI BIOS) is still messing with some BCD entries somehow.
But I got the access to my BIOS settings back, and even managed to add boot entries for Zorin OS and Haiku.